# TFS Online Build Fails with Could not find part of the path

Tags: tfs, build

My build fails with

Could not find a part of the path 'App_Data\aspnet-Definiti.Licencing.TestWebProduct-20171016042403.mdf'.

- The file exists in in the file system
- The file exists in Source Control
- The get sources phase seems to find the file fine

2017-11-28T10:49:32.5448880Z Getting aspnet-Definiti.Licencing.TestWebProduct-20171016042403.mdf (no errors here)

Things I've tried:

- Excluding the file from the project
- Deleting the file in visual studio and checking in
- Deleting the file in Source Control Explorer and Checking in
- Setting the file to copy if newer
- Setting the file to copy always
- Unticking build in configuration manager for the offending project

The error always comes back.

Copying App_Data\aspnet-Definiti.Licencing.TestWebProduct-20171016042403.mdf to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\App_Data\aspnet-Definiti.Licencing.TestWebProduct-20171016042403.mdf.
2017-11-28T10:50:48.4423213Z ##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2603,5): Error : Copying file App_Data\aspnet-Definiti.Licencing.TestWebProduct-20171016042403.mdf to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\App_Data\aspnet-Definiti.Licencing.TestWebProduct-20171016042403.mdf failed. Could not find a part of the path 'App_Data\aspnet-Definiti.Licencing.TestWebProduct-20171016042403.mdf'.

My final act of sheer desperation was to remove the entire project so at least the rest of the solution would build, but to my utter surprise the error still remains.

Comment: Nevermind. The solution was to set the file to "Do not copy".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was to set the file to do not copy and clear the MSBuild Arguments in the build definition.

Comment: Where is the "build definition?"

Comment: You are missing the how